# Can I prevent my full screen windows from being mixed around?

Tags: macos, mission-control

I use my Mac for personal, school, and work use and as you can imagine it's really easy to get cluttered up with a ton of windows. The solution I devised is separate desktops for home and work, separate full screen safari tabs, separate Xcode windows, etc. The only problem is macOS loves to jumble to ordering around. When I click links in mail they will open in safari, but then the safari window will move around in mission control. I don't want that. I want the work windows to stay together and the home windows to stay together. Is there any way to keep these windows in their place?